# CodeIgniter 4 Session Login not Worked

Tags: php, authentication, session, codeigniter-4

I have a problem about session login in my project. After input username and password, it not directly opened the admin page, but back to login form and show message "Username dan Password Salah"
Is it something wrong with this controller code?

````
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use App\Models\LoginModel;

/**
 * 
 */
class Login extends Controller
{
    
    public function index()
    {
        helper(['form']);
        echo view('formlogin');
    }

    public function auth()
    {
        $session = session();
        $model = new LoginModel();
        $username = $this->request->getVar('username');
        $password = $this->request->getVar('password');

        $data = $model->where('username', $username)->first();

        if ($data) {
            $pass = $data['password'];
            $verify = password_verify($password, $pass);
            if ($verify) {
                $session_data = [
                    'id_login' => $data['id_login'],
                    'username' => $data['username'],
                    'password' => $data['password'],
                    'logged_in' => TRUE
                ];
                $session->set($session_data);
                
                return redirect()->to('/adminsuper');
            }else{
                $session->setFlashdata('msg', 'Username dan Password Salah');

                return redirect()->to('/login');
            }
        }else{
            $session->setFlashdata('msg','Pengguna Tidak Terdaftar');
            return redirect()->to('/login');
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $session = session();
        $session->destroy();
        return redirect()->to('/login');
    }
}
?>```
````

Comment: It seems ``password_verify($password, $pass)`` method returns a false. Maybe the password and the password hash is different?

Comment: Solved. I forgot to hashing password value